# Powershell Compare-Object on large directory trees

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to do this:

```
$snap1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path \\file_path1\blah | select -ExpandProperty Fullname

$snap2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path \\file_path2\blah2 | select -ExpandProperty Fullname

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $snap1 -DifferenceObject $snap2 -IncludeEqual | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\my_username\desktop\output.txt
```

The two Get-ChildItem commands start at a folder that is the top of a directory tree and recurses down, they are mostly the same but we need to determine where the two differ and have it spit out the full file paths. One snag is that they represent about 5 million files each, which is a ton, once loaded in they seem to take up about 20 GB of RAM but this machine has 128 GB so it's not the end of the world (space efficiency shouldn't be a major issue).

This command should work, it doesn't error out and it creates the "Output.txt" file but then nothing gets written into it and it seems to just stall (there's no way I can see to tell how it is running as far as I know).

My question is for the more powershell experienced, is this good syntax for the command? Is there a better way especially considering the size of each of the file systems that are being compared?

EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
$snap1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path \\server\blah$

$snap2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path \\server\blah2$

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $snap1 -DifferenceObject $snap2 | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\comparison.txt
```

Which had the same issue where it got to the Compare-Object and actually wrote some files but seemingly stopped (however I didn't mention it because I didn't include the "equals" parameter so figured it just wasn't finding many differences.

Comment: What are you going to do? You have 2 arrays of FullNames from different roots (servers). They can never be equal, because they're fullNames, including serverName

Comment: Okay well they are the same server, I just did a bad job of shrouding the names, it should be \\file_path1\blah then \\file_path2\blah but you are absolutely correct, if it's comparing the full paths then it won't work, shoot. Is there a way to have them compare the path below the "blah" level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start point, use raw .net method [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles):

```
$snap1 = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('S:\SCRIPTS', '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
```

If this is one-time procedure and you need to compare relative paths, do substring from file names ( for example to remove first 10 symbols of server name )

```
$snap1 = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('S:\SCRIPTS', '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | 
    ForEach-Object { return $_.SubString(10) }
```

If you need FileNames, without directory name at all, make this:

```
$snap1 = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('S:\SCRIPTS', '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | 
    ForEach-Object { return [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) }
```

... And `$snap2` the same way

EnumerateFiles works MUCH faster because `Get-ChildItem` also reads `FileInfo` ( like size, length, creation time, attributes, etc ) for EACH file, and `EnumerateFiles` returns only full names.

Comment: Oh you're also the commenter above, so if I want to compare the file names and then spit out the full paths for any one that's different, is that doable?

Comment: Updated comment